# how to find the cells which values are a string type inside a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, when I tried to calcualte pct_change(), it shows me an error of
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'`. Then I tried to convert the type into float, it shows me `ValueError: could not convert string to float`:

```
unemployment_df['Unemployment_pct_change'] = unemployment_df['Unemployment_Value'].pct_change()

unemployment_df['Unemployment_Value']=unemployment_df['Unemployment_Value'].astype(float)
```

But I don't know where are the strings and what kind of strings they are? so I am trying to find the cell index where cell value is a string instead of a number. How to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`astype(float)` might work otherwise there is an option

```
unemployment_df['Unemployment_Value']=pd.to_numeric(unemployment_df['Unemployment_Value'])
```

then you can calculate the pct_change

```
unemployment_df['Unemployment_pct_change'] = unemployment_df['Unemployment_Value'].pct_change()
```

Comment: I did below as well. it show an error of ValueError: Unable to parse string " " at position 872 
 ```unemployment_df['Unemployment_Value']=pd.to_numeric(unemployment_df['Unemployment_Value']) ```

Comment: whcih means there is an empty string in your dataset. if you want replace with 0

Comment: Thanks how to drop empty string?

Comment: `df = df[df.column != '']`. this is just a sample. to get more options you can google ;)

Comment: Thank you  Subbu VidyaSekar. It works.  ``` unemployment_df=unemployment_df[unemployment_df.Unemployment_Value !=' '] ```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas doesn't really distinguish between types more granular than `object`.

```
df[df['col']].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))
```

will give you the rows that contain strings in column `'col'`

You could then clean them up however you wish.

Comment: Thanks nimish:   I did below, it show empty with an error of ValueError: Unable to parse string ```unemployment_df['istring']=unemployment_df['Unemployment_Value'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))

unemployment_df_string=unemployment_df.loc[unemployment_df['istring']=='True',:]

print(unemployment_df_string.head()) ```